# lxc-snapshot fails with rc 1 for no apparent reason

Tags: snapshot, linux-containers

At my side `lxc-snapshot` fails, but does not tell anything.

- Tried to Google for it, not found anything.  All is for `lxc snapshot` (note the missing dash) which is something completely different.
- Looked into manual, etc. nothing found.
- `strace` is not telling anything either, it talks to the anonymous command socket, gets a response and fails

```
$ lxc-start b2
$ lxc-attach b2
#
```

So container is running.  But snapshot does not work:

```
$ lxc-snapshot b2; echo $?
1
$ lxc-snapshot b2 -L
No snapshots
```

Problem exist on Debian Buster:

```
$ lxc-snapshot --version
3.0.3
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:    10
Codename:   buster
```

Problem exist on Ubuntu, too:

```
$ lxc-snapshot --version
4.0.2
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

Container configuration:

```
lxc.include = /usr/share/lxc/config/common.conf
lxc.include = /usr/share/lxc/config/userns.conf
lxc.arch = linux64
lxc.uts.name = b2
lxc.rootfs.path = dir:/home/tino/.local/share/lxc/b2/rootfs
lxc.net.0.type = veth
lxc.net.0.link = lxcbr0
lxc.net.0.flags = up
lxc.net.0.hwaddr = 00:16:3e:d2:0e:02
lxc.idmap = u 0 638752 65536
lxc.idmap = g 0 638752 65536
```

What am I missing here?  The questions are:

- How to find/enable diagnostics?
- Where is this documented?
- What do I (perhaps) need in Container's `config`?

You can point to `lxc`, `lxd` or `docker` for diagnostic purpose.  But please note that this question is not about them, it's precisely about the low level container commands like `lxc-start` and `lxc-snapshot` (note the dash).

Answer (score 0):

The manual states:

```
   -l, --logpriority=LEVEL
          Set log priority to LEVEL. The default log priority is ERROR.  Possible  values
          are : FATAL, CRIT, WARN, ERROR, NOTICE, INFO, DEBUG.

          Note  that  this option is setting the priority of the events log in the alter‐
          nate log file. It do not have effect on the ERROR events log on stderr.
```

This apparently is wrong.  Logging to `stderr` is affected by `-l` and it isn't ERROR by default:

```
$ lxc-start b2
$ lxc-snapshot -lERROR b2 2>/dev/null; echo $?
1
$ lxc-snapshot -lERROR b2
lxc-snapshot: b2: lxccontainer.c: do_lxcapi_snapshot: 4190 Snapshot of directory-backed container requested
lxc-snapshot: b2: lxccontainer.c: do_lxcapi_snapshot: 4191 Making a copy-clone.  If you do want snapshots, then
lxc-snapshot: b2: lxccontainer.c: do_lxcapi_snapshot: 4192 please create overlay clone first, snapshot that
lxc-snapshot: b2: lxccontainer.c: do_lxcapi_snapshot: 4193 and keep the original container pristine
lxc-snapshot: b2: lxccontainer.c: do_lxcapi_clone: 3809 error: Original container (b2) is running. Use --allowrunning if you want to force a snapshot of the running container.
lxc-snapshot: b2: lxccontainer.c: do_lxcapi_snapshot: 4199 Failed to clone of /home/tino/.local/share/lxc:b2
lxc-snapshot: b2: tools/lxc_snapshot.c: do_snapshot: 199 Error creating a snapshot
```

Hence, **`lxc-snapshot` only works on stopped containers** and you only see errors if you enable logging.  On a stopped container it works:

```
$ lxc-stop b2
$ lxc-snapshot -n b2 -L
No snapshots
$ lxc-snapshot -n b2
$ lxc-snapshot -n b2 -L
snap0 (/home/tino/.local/share/lxc/b2/snaps) 2020:11:25 12:22:03
$ ls -al ~/.local/share/lxc/b2/snaps/snap0/
total 20
drwxrwx---  3 638752 tino   4096 Nov 25 12:22 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 tino   tino   4096 Nov 25 12:20 ..
-rw-rw----  1 tino   tino   1171 Nov 25 12:22 config
drwxr-xr-x 21 638752 638752 4096 Nov 24 20:01 rootfs
-rw-rw-r--  1 tino   tino     19 Nov 25 12:22 ts
$ cat ~/.local/share/lxc/b2/snaps/snap0/ts; echo
2020:11:25 12:22:03
```

Notes:

- `--allowrunning` is not mentioned in the man page either
- `lxc-snapshot` appears to mostly wrap `rsync` (in this case).

This solution was found by looking up [the implementation of the snapshot function on GitHub](https://github.com/lxc/lxc/blob/dd8d55091991d7cbbef20b93a06fd500d0d8e4d2/src/lxc/lxccontainer.c#L4134) and digging deeper and deeper and deeper, getting completely lost and finally giving up on this path.  Then I wrote above Question, and, while doing that, I luckily stumbled over the solution myself.  [Don't Panic](https://h2g2.com/), sometimes the [solution](https://h2g2.com/edited_entry/A19229763) seems to be just [to ask the right way](https://h2g2.com/edited_entry/A1063531).